# Build ios development environment - Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes) error bundler: failed to load command:

Tags: react-native, environment

run npx react-native init AwesomeProject,but I receive the error:
Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error bundler: failed to load command: pod (/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/pod)
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file), '/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')) - /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi.rb:5:in require' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi.rb:5:in rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi.rb:2:in <top (required)>' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in require'
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in <top (required)>' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in require'
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in <top (required)>' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in require'
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in download_typhoeus_impl_async' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in download_and_save_with_retries_async'
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in download_file_async' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in download_file'
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in refresh_metadata' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in initialize'
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in initialize' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in new'
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in block in source_from_path' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in source_from_path'
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in block in aggregate_with_repos' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in map'
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in aggregate_with_repos' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in aggregate'
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in all' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in repo_information'
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in stack' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in report'
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in report_error' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in handle_exception'
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in rescue in run' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in run'
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in run' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/bin/pod:55:in <top (required)>'
/Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/pod:23:in load' /Users/nangongmoyan/code/home/personal/front-end/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/pod:23:in <top (required)>'
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=macos&platform=android and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Output of npx react-native info:

npx react-native info
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
OS: macOS 14.1.1
CPU: (12) x64 Apple M2 Max
Memory: 1.39 GB / 32.00 GB
Shell:
version: "5.9"
path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node:
version: 20.9.0
path: /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn:
version: 1.22.21
path: /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm:
version: 10.1.0
path: /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman:
version: 2023.11.20.00
path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods:
version: 1.14.3
path: /Users/nangongmoyan/.rbenv/shims/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms:

- DriverKit 23.0
- iOS 17.0
- macOS 14.0
- tvOS 17.0
- watchOS 10.0
  Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2022.3 AI-223.8836.35.2231.10671973
  Xcode:
  version: 15.0.1/15A507
  path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
  Java: Not Found
  Ruby:
  version: 2.7.6
  path: /Users/nangongmoyan/.rbenv/shims/ruby
  npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
  installed: 18.2.0
  wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
  installed: 0.72.7
  wanted: 0.72.7
  react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
  "react-native": Not Found
  Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
  iOS:
  hermesEnabled: Not found
  newArchEnabled: Not found

I prefix all installations with arch -arm64，but I also receive error, what should I do now? can your help me set up a good development environment? thanks.

Comment: Try `npx react-native init AwesomeProject --npm`. I've noticed that the `--npm` flag is a requirement now, but I haven't discovered why this is.